# What's the proper way to deal with someone who Team Kills and harasses you constantly in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

**What can be done against individuals who Team Kills (TK) in games of Starcraft 2?**

I don't play the game too much, but *it seems this individual does* and sometimes we're paired up as teammates in 3v3 quick matches.  I believe the first time we paired up together we didn't win and I was blamed for the loss by the individual (maybe this was true-- I'm still trying to learn the game).  Apparently this person remembers my SC2 screen name, and in subsequent games together the individual calls out that he will TK me and rushes my base with his units to kill off my buildings, and everyone on my team taking the loss.

*It seems like harassment and abuse to me.*  This individual is taking the game a little too seriously.  Is there a place to report this?  Does Blizzard have any policies against this kind of poor sportsmanship?

If I could, I wouldn't ever pair up with kind of player, but the Battle.net system keeps pairing us up!

Comment: you find those types in all kind of games. Usually you can't report to an instance (like maybe here). What I do is: quit the game, play another one. I'm there to have fun, even if it costs an instant loss.

Comment: StampedeXV makes a good suggestion, you might as well bail immediately.   Another suggestion is to try to avoid this problem in the first place: if another player starts raging at you in game, the correct thing to do is ignore them.   Even if they are totally out of line, getting into an argument is just a waste of your time and can end up with someone starting a silly "vendetta" like this.  In my experience, you don't get harassed past the first angry comment if you don't reply.  I could be wrong, but I'm guessing you guys had a nice big argument during your first game together.

Comment: I actually don't talk much in game, nor talk smack.  I just like playing and communicating strategy.  This individual was full of rage.

Comment: social-engineer their address and write a strongly worded letter about how displeased you are with them

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sadly there is no method by which you can prevent being matched with another player without breaking ToU, however Team Killing is a form of harassment and can get you banned if reported.  I would suggest you contact blizzard support as soon as possible.

Webform: [Email Form](http://us.blizzard.com/support/webform.xml)

For detailed information on how to contact Account Administration visit the [Account Administration page](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article/contactaccountadmin).

For assistance with StarCraft II in other regions such as Europe, Korea, or China, please refer to our [International Support Contact page](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article/international).

Comment: Blizzard handed out tons of bans on the first day of play.  They are committed to keeping this game fun for everyone.

Comment: I miss those old Starcraft days when you bs

Comment: @StrixVaria: How do you know about bans? Any source?

Comment: Can anyone comment how to report this-- how to prove this, are replays necessary to be saved as evidence?

Comment: @Sunpech you can find information about contacting blizzard support here: http://us.blizzard.com/support/index.xml?locale=en_US&gameId=13&rootCategoryId=4511

Answer (score 4):

About contacting Blizzard (from [Blizzard Support](http://us.blizzard.com/support/index.xml?locale=en_US&gameId=13&rootCategoryId=4511) page):

> Webform: [Email Form](http://us.blizzard.com/support/webform.xml)
>
> For detailed information on how to contact Account Administration visit the [Account Administration page](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article/contactaccountadmin).
>
> For assistance with StarCraft II in other regions such as Europe, Korea, or China, please refer to our [International Support Contact page](http://us.blizzard.com/support/article/international).

So it looks like you can send a complain about harassment by filling out their Email Form.

Comment: FYI: I merged yours and [tzenes' answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4958/whats-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-someone-who-team-kills-and-harasses-you-consta/4960#4960) as I think that's what you meant to do but couldn't. :)

Answer (score 1):

While in game there are options to block a player or report a player's actions directly to blizzard. If nothing else, block them.  If they're blocked you won't be matched with them in future games.

Comment: As a suggestion for improvement of the forum... it would be more informative if you could provide the steps to do that - "Go to page X, click on Y", etc. This also applies to tzenes' response - "Contact Blizzard" - how? A specific email address? A particular page on their website? In game?

Comment: Can anyone verify if this actually blocks a player?  I don't think it does anything more than squelch/ignore all communication from the player.

Comment: @sunpech you are correct that only squelches communication it does not block them from joining games you're in or prevent you from joining games their in, or even prevent the two of you from being matched in ladder play (though the odds of that are low). Webnet is misinformed on this issue.