# Is there a banlist or way to block certain players from being in the games you play in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

Is there a banlist or way to block certain players from being in the games you play?

**Update**
- *To clarify, the banlist I mention is a personal ban list on your account.  It's not a public banlist on Blizzard.*

**Update #2**
- *Further clarification of what a Banlist is*.  I'm interested in the blocking/banning aspect and maybe even the safelisting-- essentially a system to write and save a comment about players you encounter and play with.

From [About WC3 Banlist](http://www.wc3banlist.de/about.php):

> This program is created to make an
>   effort at keeping your Warcraft III
>   custom games (for example DotA) free
>   of notorious leavers. Thereby it
>   offers a local database (to which you
>   can add people yourself) to alert you
>   when a "leaver" joins your game or
>   someone you've kept some information
>   about.
>
> The program can do this in various
>   ways:
>
> - Play a sound as soon as a leaver is detected, or banned
> - Display a text in-game floating at the top of your screen
> - Copy a text into the clipboard, so you can view the comment by pressing CTRL-V
>
> Further features include:
>
> - Synchronization with other people's banlists via the Banlist.nl Buddy Banlist System
> - Integration of clans' banlists / safelists
> - Showing the country of or ping to joined players or the host
> - A real-time chat interface for Warcraft III using built-in stylesheets to match the Warcraft III-look or another look to your liking
> - An anti-download option which
>     enables you to have people who try to
>     download the map (when hosting)
>     auto-kicked
> - Automatic slot-reservation
>     for your friends and clanmates
> - Automatically copying the game name if
>     your friend joins a game

Comment: it would be nice to block the "I'm going to hide my CC in the corner of the map so the game won't end until you can build a mutalisk to come kill it" kind of players.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the proper way to deal with someone who Team Kills and harasses you constantly in Starcraft 2?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4958/whats-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-someone-who-team-kills-and-harasses-you-consta)

Comment: and don't get me started on the fake GGers.  they are like a con man saying "thank you" as they steal your money.

Comment: @tzenes I don't think it's a duplicate at all. I asked the question on that post too. The answer accepted on that was to report the abuse to Blizzard. This post specifically asks if there is a way to block/ban a player from games you are in, which may not necessarily have anything to do with TKing or abuse/harassment. The very heart of the questions are different, but the answers yielded may be similar. I don't think that warrants a close or a vote down.

Comment: @sunpech I think that an answer that gave how to block would be useful to the question I linked as well as this one. I don't really see the purpose in producing that information in two places, or having each question link to the others. It seems to me, the situation is simple enough: you did not get an answer about blocking to the first question.  The solution is not to open a new question, but request additional answers. To help facilitate this I would recommend offering a bounty on the original question to anyone who can supply a blocking method.  If you lack the rep I am willing to supply.

Comment: @Kyralessa that is considered proper etiquette for the loser to admit defeat by saying "gg."  For a winner to say "gg" first is considered "bm" or bad manners.  There are also people who will say "gg" and then continue to fight as if they had a chance to win (and possibly go on to win), this is also considered "bm," and sometimes cheating.

Comment: As a winner, the only time I will say GG before the loser is when its obvious they lost but they just run around building pylons, nexus in random places even when there are no minerals near by, or as terran fly their command center in the corner of the map until you get air units to kill it.  They make no obvious attempt at getting back in the game.

Comment: @kyra Good Luck and Have Fun are considered standard greetings (usually in the form of "glhf").  Its a shame you didn't ask this all in a single question so we could collect the data there.

Comment: the fake GGers I was referring to were the ones that say GG as if they are surrendering, then continue to fight.  usually this happens if they have an extra base hidden away somewhere that they don't think you know about.  I think the idea is to trick you into letting down your guard.

Comment: @tzenes I respectfully disagree. You are trying to link 2 answers together from 2 different questions. Duplicate questions, yes, should be discouraged and closed. But duplicate answers will be very commonplace on a Q&A site. SE is about asking specific questions and getting them answered. Trying to link and create sub-questions/sub-answers to other questions/answers is a mess. This question is big enough on it's own here and was only a thoughtful answer (and unaccepted) to the linked post you claim to be a duplicate.

Comment: @sunpech I'm sorry but the established protocol is to eliminate duplicate answers: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1325/editing-and-retagging-to-make-a-duplicate-fit there is no real reason to have the same information in two different places.

Comment: @tzenes Did you provide the correct link? You linked to a SU site, which is a different community than Gaming.SE.

Comment: @sunpech the standpoint is not unique to SU, here it is on SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/when-is-a-duplicate-question-not-a-duplicate/12184#12184 I could link from the other stackexchange family too.  A duplicate question is one that receives the same answer.  Since there is no answer to this question that wouldn't be a good answer to the other, vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

No. There isn't. Especially not on the ladder. Then you could say "Block everyone else in the top 200", and you'd never lose! (if you were good enough to beat everyone else)

Comment: but you would not get many points for beating people that were so far below you, so that should be counterproductive, if the rating algorithm makes any sense at all.

Comment: @PeterRecore it doesn't matter, people like to win more than they like to have a good rating.   This is this is the same reason people engage in smurfing.

Comment: @T M people are jerks then ;)

Comment: @PeterRecore Yup.

Comment: I think this may be the correct answer.  At least Blizzard/Battle.net doesn't offer any kind of banlist feature.  Only squelching/muting communication.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4958/whats-the-proper-way-to-deal-with-someone-who-team-kills-and-harasses-you-consta/4985#4985), you can block players and you will no longer be matched with them. This is the equivalent of how WoW's Looking-for-dungeon feature will not group you with people on your ignore list. I'm not sure if this will prevent you from playing *against* them.

Comment: Well, can you please document how that occurs?

Comment: I'll let my choice of upvote depend on whoever puts in a link that settles this

Comment: I think this block feature only squelch/ignores communication from that player.  I don't believe it will stop the player from being paired with or against you.